# Avoid user typing delay in input textfield box mudblazor blazor c#

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have a mud blazor grid with pagination/global search. The search functionality works as expected when I test it in my local i.e it filters out the grid as soon as the user types in something and it seems to be really fast. The problem occurs when I host it to dev/stage server. The user input is delayed. Also, it works fine if the input is entered slowly. For instance, if I try to enter "test" into the searchbox quite fast then it always misses 1 or 2 characters and prints it as "tst" even though I've typed all the characters carefully. The pointer flickers very frequently on pressing backspace.

I tried to clear the cache but still doesn't work after hosting whereas no such problem occurs when doing the above in my local env.

I can't figure out what have I done wrong as in why the performance is affected.
**Note: I'm loading the dataset at once from db (inside onInitialized())**

The code:

Index.razor

```
<MudTable Items="CustomersWithOrderInfo" ServerData="new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<Data.Models.CustomerOrderInfoDTO>>>(LoadCustomers)" FixedHeader="true" FixedFooter="true" Class="table table-hover" Style="box-shadow:none !important;" @ref="table" Height="530px">
                        <ToolBarContent>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width:35%;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="@searchString" @oninput="@FilterChanged">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text bg-primary" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg fa-charade text-white" style="font-size:small;"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </ToolBarContent>
                        <HeaderContent>
                            <MudTh Style="font-weight: bold;width:12%;">Customer Id</MudTh>
                            <MudTh Style="font-weight: bold;width:13%">Customer Name</MudTh>
                             ....
                            <MudTh Style="font-weight: bold;width:8%;">Actions</MudTh>
                        </HeaderContent>
                        <RowTemplate>
                                                 
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Customer Id">@context.CustomerId</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Customer Name">@context.CustomerName</MudTd>
                             ....
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Active">@context.IsActive</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="">
                            
                               ...
                            </MudTd>
                        </RowTemplate>
                        <PagerContent>
                            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="pageSizes" />
                        </PagerContent>
                    </MudTable>
```

IndexBase.cs

```
 protected void FilterChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            searchString = args.Value.ToString();
            table.ReloadServerData();
        }
protected async Task<TableData<CustomerOrderInfoDTO>> LoadCustomers(TableState tableState)
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerOrderInfoDTO> data = CustomersWithOrderInfo.OrderByDescending(q => q.CustomerId);
            data = data.Where(p =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
                    return true;
               
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CustomerName) && p.CustomerName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return true;
               
                if ($"{p.CustomerId}".Contains(searchString))
                    return true;
                return false;

            }).ToArray();
            totalItems = data.Count();
            pagedData = data.Skip(tableState.Page * tableState.PageSize).Take(tableState.PageSize).ToArray();
            return new TableData<CustomerOrderInfoDTO>() { TotalItems = totalItems, Items = pagedData };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you used `@oninput="@FilterChanged"`, this means this will execute `FilterChanged` every time you type a character. Since `FilterChanged` is a function that takes some time, this creates some lags to the UI while it executes.

Try replacing `@oninput="@FilterChanged"` by `@onchange="@FilterChanged"`. This will execute `FilterChanged` when the element loses focus.

Another possibility would be to add a button or to execute when `Enter` key is pressed.

See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Or debounce the actual operation and rerender while still using oninput

Comment: Could you elaborate @rdmptn

Comment: I think rerenders and requesting the data to often are the issue, I have seen such filtering be debounced with great success, regardless of server/wasm deployment (of latency is too high for the server flavor that's a separate issue). I'm not at a pc now so I can't make a sample of debouncing but a timer instance is used and you reset it every time the event happens, then when it finally times out, you execute the slow operation that grabs data and rerenders.

Comment: @rdmptn I agree but the latency might be part of the issue since the author seems to say it does not lag locally but when deployed on a dev/stage server.

Comment: Could be. Could also be the slower real real data source that blocks the renders as well while waiting for data

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue on Ant Blazor. Typing is fine if slow, but if I type quickly characters start getting dropped. The fix is super easy: add DebounceMilliseconds="1000" to your input component.

For example
<input DebounceMilliseconds="1000" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="@searchString" @oninput="@FilterChanged">

Explanation on why it works (credit to https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/issues/1283#issuecomment-810108270):

> Due to the way inputs work, the string that is 2 way-bounded from the
> input form gets updated from the string to the text box.
>
> In a Blazor Server scenario, with latency being a thing (imagine 200ms
> for an average request), if you send multiple updates to the server,
> they will respond back to you with state, but you already typed more.
>
> One way to fix this is to set the debounce time to be 1 or 2+ seconds
>
> - such that with slow internet no request will be sent while typing is happening.
>
> If you are using an enter key or button to submit/search etc - you may
> use an absurdly large debounce time, as the onblur event will cause an
> update (think tabbing out, clicking somewhere else).